# how to draw a line with plane end in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to draw a line like the yellow one or the cyan one with the plane end.However, if I simply use the 'cv2.line' or 'cv2.ellipse' command, it just draws a blue one or green one with curved ends.

I have tried these code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)  
cv2.line(img,(40,100),(480,100),(255,0,0),30)
cv2.ellipse(img,(150,250),(80,80),0,45,225,(0,255,0),30,cv2.CV_AA)

cv2.rectangle(img,(40,400),(480,430),(0,255,255),-1,cv2.CV_AA)
cv2.ellipse(img,(400,250),(80,80),0,45,225,(255,255,0),-1,cv2.CV_AA)
cv2.circle(img,(400,250),50,(0,0,0),-1,cv2.CV_AA)
```

It works, but I don't think it's a good way.I want to know that whether there is an easier and more common way to achieve that.

Thanks for any help.

[image: two lines]

Comment: welcome to SO, try to show your work in your question.

Comment: I have implanted an image, but it seems become a link and I can't make it displayed directly.

Comment: Hi, @Alvin. Since you are new to Stack Overflow, I would highly recommend taking the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Secondly, your question is missing some key information that makes it a quality question, which makes it less likely to be answered. Please read have a read of [How do I ask a question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidance on the changes you should make. Finally, checkout the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for information on how to use the editor, such as adding [images](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)

Comment: Thanks for your help and recommendation. I've added what  I've done.